# How do I add 4 spaces to all the code when I want to ask a question?. Im doing it line by line(It take me a lot time)

Tags: support, asking-questions, questions

I have a big code and need to ask about it. How in the space for the question do I avoid adding 4 spaces to each line. I need do it faster.

Comment: see [How to move a block of code by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2621/579)